# Entity not found and err is still nil

Tags: go, go-gorm

I'm trying to select an entity by a token.

```
var event models.Event
err := p.db.Preload("Groups.Participants").Find(&event, "token = ?", token).Error
return event, err
```

But if I pass an empty `token`, eg. "" or another non existing token. I don't get an error, I simple get an unpopulated event. I could check if event.ID == 0 but I feel that is a bit odd. I'm a bit surprised that `err` is still nil even though no entity is found.

Am I do doing something wrong? is there a better way to handle the above?

Comment: `Find` is for retrieving multiple objects and that usually doesn't return a no-rows error. If you want the no-rows error use one of these: https://gorm.io/docs/query.html#Retrieving-a-single-object. This is the same behavior as the standard library's `Query` and `QueryRow`. `Query` does not return an error if no row is found. `QueryRow` does return `sql.ErrNoRows` if no row is found.

Comment: Use First() instead of Find()

Comment: Thanks for the support guys, if either of you turn your comment into an answer I'll accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Find` does not result in an error if no records are found. This is mentioned as a side note in the documentation on [single object retrieval](https://gorm.io/docs/query.html#Retrieving-a-single-object):

> If you want to avoid the `ErrRecordNotFound` error, you could use `Find`
> like `db.Limit(1).Find(&user)`, the `Find` method accepts both struct and
> slice data

If you have to use `Find` then you'll have to check for no-record yourself by checking for zero values when using it to retrieve a single object, or by checking the slices length against zero when using it to retrieve multiple objects. But, if you're retrieving only a single object, then I'd recommend you use one of the methods documented in that link, i.e. `First`, `Take`, or `Last`, as the documentation illustrates, these methods do result in the `ErrRecordNotFound` error when no record satisfying the query is found.